# My touchpad works like a touchscreen

Tags: touchpad, 16.10, touchscreen

So I recently installed Ubuntu on my Alienware/Dell and everything was fine until I upgraded to 16.10.

After that out of nowhere my touchpad started acting like a touchscreen (or a graphics tablet) i.e. the pointer jumps to wherever I touch on the pad(like its mapped to the screen.

I tried everything I could find, namely remapping `xinput` or even removing and adding the mouse module `psmouse` but nothing worked. I could not find any other solution to this.

Output of `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` is the one that I am talking about.

Output of `xinput list-props 14`

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (165):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (167): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (295): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (296):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (297):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (298):    10.000000
Device Product ID (284):    2, 7
Device Node (285):  "/dev/input/event6"
Evdev Axis Inversion (299): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (300):   <no items>
Evdev Axes Swap (301):  0
Axis Labels (302):  "Abs MT Position X" (292), "Abs MT Position Y" (293), "Abs MT Pressure" (294), "Abs Tool Width" (291), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0)
Button Labels (303):    "Button Left" (168), "Button Unknown" (287), "Button Right" (170), "Button Wheel Up" (171), "Button Wheel Down" (172)
Evdev Scrolling Distance (304): 0, 0, 0
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (305):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (306):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (307): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (308): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (309):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (310):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (311):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (312):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (313):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (314):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (315): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (316):  0
```

I also noticed that people out there get a problem opposite to mine (i.e. their touchscreen acts like a touchpad)

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: What do you call "act like a touchscreen", or "act like a touchpad"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: I will add the `xinput` output as soon as I can

Comment: added the `xinput` output

Comment: Please also add the output of `xinput list-props 14`

Comment: added the output

Comment: OK. Now I see the problem. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no user space touchpad driver installed. That is why it is treated like a relative device.

Run

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

and restart the session.

If you have `hwe-16.04` packages installed, you need to run

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: Well, I might sound stupid right about now. That fixed my problem. How did you know that the drivers are missing

Comment: I see that the device is handled by `evdev`, not by `synaptics` or `libinput`. You can check it now.

Comment: yea saw that right now. i did try installing libinput but i guess I didn't know enough. Thanks, you made my day

Comment: That means that none of those were installed.

Comment: weird, I wonder how that got uninstalled in the update.

Comment: This kind of things do happen from time to time. A bug in the upgrade path.

Comment: I got the same bug, with the same solution. In my case, I had previously installed `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack); installing `xserver-xorg-input-all` removed the hwe versions and put me back on "normal" packages. Could it be that this upgrade bug only happens to people who tried the HWE package (or otherwise had "odd" xserver packages installed)?

Comment: You could install `xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04`.

Comment: Pilot6, I believe that package is gone from yakkety: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04 (hence the name 16.04 in the package name?)

Comment: @unhammer This package is only for `xenial`. In `yakkety` you use `xserver-xorg-input-all`.

Comment: The question is about upgrading to 16.10 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Setting you are looking for is relative- or absolute tracking mode.

This is hardware specific, to find your device, list your devices with the `xinput` command (without any options). Look for a "slave" device, which is the actual device, not the master device which is virtual.

xinput set-mode  ABSOLUTE|RELATIVE will change the mode. Device name can be the Xid number reported by `xinput` or the actual name, including the quotation marks: `xinput set-mode "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" RELATIVE`. Xinput options: https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml

If you are using a Wacom pad or tablet simply open the wacom settings window found in ubuntu system settings and click the relevant option. For more on Wacom see help.ubuntu at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom-mode.html

Comment: It only speaks about wacom tablet, I have a touchpad in my laptop

Comment: What make and model is your device? See Pilot6's request for output of xinput.

Comment: added the `xinput` output

Comment: I do believe that is what I am finding. I think I need to switch to relative tracking mode

Comment: 'xinput set-mode "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" RELATIVE' might be worth trying?

Comment: I did it but it did not work changed it a couple of times, didn't work

Comment: Did xinput set-mode command return anything?