# Wacom Intuous tablet not mapping to single monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, tablet, wacom

After a recent kernel upgrade, I lost the use of my Wacom tablet (Wacom Intuos Pro Pen and Touch Tablet, Large).  I used to use the tablet together with Xournal++ to take notes for my online lectures.  From September up until ~October 15, the tablet and pen worked perfectly.  I would be able to map the tablet to a single monitor/display.  I use three monitors/displays: the laptop screen, one connected via the USB-C port, and the third via the HDMI port).  The tablet was mapped to the one connected to the HDMI port.

Now, since the latest kernel upgrade (5.4.0-52 64-bit kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.3), I am unable to map the tablet to a single monitor/display (any of the three).  As a result, and since I use three monitors/displays, all that I write is stretched three times in the horizontal directions making it impossible to write or draw anything that would make sense to my students.

I have tried several times the different options in the Settings > Wacom Tablet > Tablet menu.  I even tried all possible combinations but no success.

Any and all help is appreciated.  Please let me know if you need additional information about the setup to help me debug.

**EDIT:** The selected answer works.  To help check the name of the device I used `xinput`  and looked for the line with the line with *stylus*  in it.

Also, to get the coordinates for the offset, or use the display name to map directly to the desired display, I used `xrandr`. [More information may be found here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor/1253939#1253939)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a bug regarding this Problem
[here](https://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg782267.html).

the Problem seems to be with the display output names. For me the Workaround with setting the output manually with worked:

```bsh
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos Pro S Pen stylus" MapToOutput 1920x1080+0+0
```

Well, I actually had to change the numbers around a bit, because, the aspect ratio and position of my desired display are different. But as a temporary workaround, while they are working on a solution this is OK for me.

the general idea with the numbers at the end is:
<width of projection>+<height of projection>+<offset x>+<offset y>
for me it was 3400x1440+3840+0

When you are using a different tablet, you might get a message, like this: `Cannot find device 'Wacom Intuos Pro S Pen stylus'.`. I was lucky enough, that I just had to switch out the `S` for an `M` (so the string was `Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus` for me) but I don't really know where to look for the value you have to use here, when using a different product.

I hope it helps.

EDT:
I forgot: I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` (with kernel version `5.4.0-52-generic`). I'm not so sure on whether or not it's the same for other distros, but yeah, still hope, that I at least notched you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @Wr4thon, that worked!!!  Before I mark this as the actual answer, please add the following: use `xinput` to find out the name of your device.  One has to pick the one that says `stylus`.  [I got that information here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890629/my-touchpad-works-like-a-touchscreen/890665#890665).  If you cannot edit, I can do that for you.  Just let me know.

Comment: Also, note that [according to this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor/1253939#1253939), one can also map directly by name of the display as opposed to giving the coordinates.  To get the display name (and coordinate too!) one only needs to do `xrandr`.

Comment: Had the same problem on Arch Linux, this fixed it for me as well.